# ¿En un output, cómo vuelvo atrás?

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico

ayer empece a aprender las bases de programación con un programa llamado raptor, y ahora mismo estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el cual le pregunto al usuario qué desea calcular (área de un triángulo o de un rectángulo).

Una vez hecho esto hago dos condicionales dependiendo de la respuesta. El problema es que configuré para que, en caso del usuario seleccionar otra opción de las posibles, le salga un output diciendo que esa opción no está disponible.

Lo que quería preguntar es como hago para que un mensaje en output me lleve de nuevo al inicio del imput (donde se le pregunta qué quiere hacer) y no al final de todo el ejercicio.

Les adjunto una foto así se ve bien. Sé que es una pavada pero les agradecería la ayuda.

Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, mira esta ayuda sobre [ask]

Comment: ese cuadro no deberia ser de otro tipo, o dejarte mover la flecha de abajo? lo que queres hacer en diseño a mano alzada se puede hacer (y es correcto).. pero en ese programa ni idea...

Comment: Pero, supongamos que esta idea la trasladara a algún lenguaje. Digamos que se llega al "fin de las cadenas de condicionales" y llegamos al último NO. 

En ese caso, hago un output que me diga que esa opción no está disponible, pero ademas: ¿se puede redireccionar al inicio de la pregunta?  

Como lo escribí yo en papel sería algo asi como: (OUTPUT: "Esta opción no está disponible" + loop)  <-- tratando de suponer que el loop indica que me redireccione a la pregunta.

¿Está bien o sería cualquier cosa?